# Importing Python packages in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to build WPF IronPython Application using Visual-Studio 2017. This is my initial code - most of it automatically generated by Visual Studio (See also figure 1):

```
import wpf  
from System import Run  
from System.Windows import Application, Window    
import pandas    
class MyWindow(Window):  
    def __init__(self):  
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication2.xaml')   
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

[image: Figure 1]

The problem is with the "import pandas" statement which Visual Studio does not recognize and does not compile.
This is despite the fact that Anaconda 5.0.1 is installed and is part of the Python Environments as the figure shows.
You can see in figure 2 the "Python Environments" window. The pandas package is recognized and was compiled for InteliSense.

[image: Figure 2]

Also I added various paths for the "pandas" package location into the search path as you can see in figure 3.

[image: Figure 3]

I also tried some Voodoo solution I found in various forum of the type of uninstall and then re-install the packages from all kind of places.
Yet I can not get the code to compile - the `import pandas` statement refuses to compile. :-(

I am feeling kind of stuck here and would appreciate your assistance.